# Is Silverlight 5 compatible with Windows XP SP2?

Tags: windows-xp, silverlight

So, is Silverlight 5 compatible with Windows XP SP2? I've searched around. Some say it is, some say it isn't some even say it depends on whether you run on 32 or 64 bit architecture.

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silverlight 5 isn't supported on XP SP2, at least officially. You can see that only XP SP3 is mentioned in the [Silverlight 5 Compatability chart](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx) (System requirements tab), whereas SP2 and SP3 are mentioned in [Silverlight 4 Compatibility chart](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL4.html).

Answer (score -2):

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_Microsoft_Silverlight_compatible_with_Windows_XP?#slide=1

Silverlight is compatible with Windows XP IF Service Pack 2 is installed.

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_Microsoft_Silverlight_compatible_with_Windows_XP?#slide=1

Comment: That answer was posted in 2010, a year before Silverlight 5 was released.